# Visual Studio Code doesn't recognize the 'and' operator in media queries

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I am working on a form in Visual Studio Code. While trying to utilize the and operator, in a media query the and operator is not being recognized. I am attempting to have a set of format rules for when the screen is less than 600px wide.

css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
/*full width when screen less than 600*/
    .form-body{
        background-color: #EEEAE9;
        border: 6px solid #000;
        width: 100%
    }
}
```

the and operator is appearing as simple text, ignoring the defining characteristic of 600 px width.
Is there a reason why css would not be recognizing the "and" operator?

Comment: please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are you talking about syntax highlighting/coloration in the editor or a functional issue?

Comment: My hunch is that you have a syntax error earlier in the file.

Comment: I believe it was caused by a syntax error earlier in the file, as the media query abruptly began working once I moved to other parts of the page. Thank you all for your help, anyhow!